# How would I send data from xcode project to a personal website and then return different data?

Tags: json, swift, xcode, http, network-programming

I am currently creating an app that will display lots of information about the bars on my college campus. Such information includes the current cover of each bar, line length, drink specials, and bar atmosphere.
The bar cover, line length, and atmosphere will be manually set by the users of the app. So, if someone goes up to the bar and sees that the cover is 15 dollars and presses the button, the app will send an integer '15' to a website that I've created and the website will then receive it and insert it into an array containing all of the covers that other people have set. Once that happens, I would like the website to then return the array to the app (or Xcode, since it is currently in development) where it can then process and display the correct data.
I've spent weeks learning JavaScript, HTTP requests, and JSON among other things, but I still haven't found a way to actually do this. It almost feels like I am missing a piece of the puzzle.

The function below is called when the user presses the button in Xcode. It is written in Swift.

```
func CreateRequest()
{
guard let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(15)//encoding the integer 15
else{
print("failed to encode")
return
}
let url=URL(string: "https://barmelsu.com") //this is my website link
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.httpBody = endoded
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) //actually sending the HTTP request
{ data, response, error in
guard let data =  data else {print("No data in response \(error?.localizedDescription)."
return}
if let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Array<Int>.self, from: data)
{
print(decoded)
}
.resume()
}
```

As I have said, it feels like it should be a very simple task but I feel like I am missing something. If anyone has any suggestions on what topics I need to learn to be able to do this it would be greatly appreciated. I am still very new to the concept of networking.

Comment: Does your website have a REST API or similar?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson no it does not, and I'm not even sure what that is

Comment: It's a way to programmatically talk to your website and you need some way to do that to be able to transfer information (data) betwen the app and the server.